# Optimize Disk Mount Parameters for EXT4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ext4, fstab

I am looking to optimize the `mount` options when mounting a disk to write large files to under linux (Ubuntu 16).

Specifically, mounting an external EXT4 USB 3 drive to backup VM files (~10G) and also copy over video files (~8G).  Copying from an internal drive to the external USB.

I started with the original fstab entry and tested different options.  Below are the original and optimized entries.

My question is this:

**Are there any other optimizations that can be made and of the current optimizations, are there any risk to data integrity?**

```
# Western Digital My Passport 25E2

# original
#UUID=4021ff7e-d371-495b-ad13-b33233fece55 /media/wd01 ext4  rw,noauto,nouser,sync 0 2

# optimized
UUID=4021ff7e-d371-495b-ad13-b33233fece55 /media/wd01 ext4  rw,noauto,nouser,data=writeback,noatime 0 2
```

- Removed `sync`, should allow optimization of writes, but must wait until all writes are complete before disconnecting
- Added `data=writeback`, better suited to writing large files
- Added `noatime`, does not update the file system for files which are simply being read, saw minor speed improvements that may be coincidental

Testing with:

```
date
sudo rsync -rv /vm/example-disk0.qcow2 /media/wd01/ \
--progress && date && tput bel && tput bel && tput bel
```

Original:

```
example-disk0.qcow2
 16,149,905,408 100%   33.59MB/s    0:07:38 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
```

Optimized:

```
example-disk0.qcow2
 16,149,905,408 100%  132.74MB/s    0:01:56 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
```